# FB Comments. Missed old comments. Wrong comment counter number

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments

I have a blog on Wordpress with installed "Simple Facebook comments" plugin. It working couple of years but some time ago i found out that for some posts Facebook API showing me "N" comments but display none.

I tried to add comment to this kind of post and comments counter showing "N+1" but i was able to see only one most recent comment. I was trying to receive all of existing comment via Open Graph API (example: http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http://blog.spafinder.ca/breaking-free-toxic-relationship/) but it returning only one comment after that i was requested comments number for the same post (REST API: http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=http://blog.spafinder.ca/breaking-free-toxic-relationship/ , GRAPH API: http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://blog.spafinder.ca/breaking-free-toxic-relationship/) and it told me that i have 2 comments.

I tried to clear OpenGraph cache, request comment number with another resources and it wasn't help.

Do you have any idea why it happening? I would be a very grateful if somebody will told me the possible way to solve that problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the url you posted, that plugin seems to be using the [Facebook Rest Server API](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/616/) which has been deprecated as noted below...

> We announced the Graph API at f8 2010. Since that event, we have been working hard to ensure that the most important functionality that developers were using with the REST API is available via the Graph API. For the past several months we have been slowly launching new features in the Graph API to bring it up to parity with the REST API

This article is 3 years old so I wouldn't be surprised to find out that there are bugs in the existing deprecated API since they have dropped support for it. That said, be sure to read the documentation of the plugin you're using, they might have updated the plugin.

Also, if you wish to do this job manually, rather than depending on a third-party, be sure to read the documentation regarding this endpoint because permissions and default filters can affect the output...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/object/comments/

Comment: Unfortunately usage of Graph API v2.0 wouldn't help me because it also return wrong number of comments.